# How to duplicate Blender glow and reflection effects in Unity?

Tags: unity, 3d, blender, reflection-rendering, glow

I am trying to make my game more interesting by making a background with this NEON tunnel made of glowing lines.

Since I am not a good 3D artist, I choose to hire some freelancers, and they made a model that looks great in Blender. I have all that I need...but when I import my object into Unity, it does not have any effects, any colors, any glow or any "mirror" reflection.

The biggest problem is that I cannot find any other freelancer who actually knows how to fix this problem.

This is how it shows up in Blender when my freelancers made it, and it looks perfect:

[image: Glowing neon tunnel with red & green walls and red ceiling, over a glossy reflective checkerboard floor]

I want to have the same effects, same look, same colors, same glow in my Unity project, but I don't know how to actually import this object and reproduce that same look.

This is all zip folder which contain pictures, object in blender file, same object in .fbx,.obj.mtl and in many more formats.. but seems like any of those models doesn't work in Unity because I bet Unity needs more modifications...

I hope someone will help me step by step to achieve my goal.

Comment: "Glow" isn't part of the model, it's part of the rendering process. So you need to set up your rendering process in Unity to create this effect, using post-processing filters like Bloom

Comment: Can you show me how with step by step, how to achieve mirror look down?!

Comment: For that, you probably want to [consult the documentation on Screen Space Reflections](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Screen-Space-Reflections.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. For mirror like ground create a material with standard Shader make the metallic value to 1 and smoothness to 0.5 and attach it to the ground which will make object like a mirror.
2. Now for the glowing objects create another material with standard Shader and then enable emission for material and then attach material to the model. for more info please follow the [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnG2gOKV9dw&t=607s).
3. For Glow use [post processing stack](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/post-processing-stack-83912). Please follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0OQvWAPeuo) for how to use [post processing stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0OQvWAPeuo).

I hope this will help.

Comment: The standard material shader alone will not cause mirror reflections of other scene objects out of the box. This controls only how the material reacts to lights and the skybox. You'll need to use screenspace reflections or reflection probes to capture reflections of scene objects.

Comment: Yes. that right but the same effect can be achieved with light backing. so i didn't feel the need of reflection prob.

Comment: No, light baking will not produce this same effect. Try it and see.

Comment: I used the mirror effect in one my game its not in real time but i backed shader emission on another object. I postest video URL in the answar section. And I am sure you are right if i want to have full environment reflection but in this case i think we only need light reflection so it can be achieved with light backing and shader emission.